# Issue installing Pygal

Tags: python, windows, cmd, windows-10, pygal

I downloaded Python 3.8.5 and have been trying to install the module pygal. It doesn't work from the Python shell, but I tried it on my command prompt. I use Windows 10. What I got below is what keeps coming up. I've tried `pip install pygal` and `install pygal`. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
>>> pip install pygal
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install pygal
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0):

You are running Python on your command prompt before entering the pip command. Just open a command prompt window and type in

```
pip install pygal
```

and press enter.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried it but I got the response below. Is there something else I need to do?                 
C:\Users\Joseph>pip install pygal
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: If you haven't installed pip yet, follow the instructions in this [link](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/). If you've already installed pip, add the path of your pip installation(_'path/to/your/python/installation/folder/Scripts'_) to your PATH variable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I was able to install pip and also install pygal from my command prompt. I tried to import pygal into my Python shell, but this is the response I received. Again, thank you for your help.                                                                                                                           >>> import pygal
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygal'
>>>

Comment: Have you tried opening a new command prompt window? because the changes from the new installation won't be applied on the already open one.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I did exit out of the old command prompt and re-ran *pip install pygal* and the command prompt said that the requirement was already satisfied. I tried putting *import pygal* into my python shell again and got this Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygal
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygal' Any thoughts? Again thanks for getting me this far, I wouldn't have done this by myself

Comment: Are you sure that the shell is using the same python installation as where you pip installed pygal?

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure. I'm trying to figure out how to change my Python Path, but it isn't working too well.